# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' | Linux Deepin IDE: Jetbrain Rider

Tags: c#, linux, sqlite, dll

So on Windows 10 fall creator update, everything works fine But on Linux (Deepin 15.5 and Ubuntu 16.04) the SQLite.Interop.dll could not be found, when it the x86 and x64 folder are made with the interop.dll there as seen [here in my screen cap](https://streamango.com/embed/rnnkddncmrmeembm/)